# uWSGI: chdir(): No such file or directory

Tags: uwsgi

I'm configuring uWSGI and with this im.ini configuration file:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins = python
chdir = '/var/www/im/'
module = texst
master = true
processes = 5
```

I'm getting chdir(): No such file or directory in UWSGI error log.

The directory is owned by www-data, dont get it. Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the chdir line (and all parameters) do not accept apostrophe nor quote marks.